# What is performed during module installation (magento connect)

Tags: module, installation

I found on internet an open source module which can help me developing some function of my own module.

I then tried to implement it on my shop to test it by copying the app directory.

But I got errors on the observer.php regarding the eval() function.

I then installed it via magento connect using the package.xml file. And it works.

I would like to understand what does the installation which is not performed by file copying.

Here is the package.xml file :

```
<package><name>GoIvvy_PriceFormula</name><license uri="http://goivvy.com">GoIvvy.com software license</license><notes /><time>00:50:53</time><__packager>build_package.py v0.0.3</__packager><summary>calculate final price based on formula</summary><stability>stable</stability><__commit_hash>b5a202c05d2618783bf8c79f20043a01fa95c255</__commit_hash><version>1.0.0.0</version><extends /><contents><target name="mageetc"><dir name="modules"><file hash="20826458b307f2088ed2d826c6879902" name="GoIvvy_PriceFormula.xml" /></dir></target><target name="magecommunity"><dir name="GoIvvy"><dir name="PriceFormula"><dir name="etc"><file hash="851feb4dec3d1aedca5630222b52dbe7" name="system.xml" /><file hash="ed74f8c3c608a262fd530e4959fa2175" name="config.xml" /></dir><dir name="Model"><file hash="5da79fe4d3ec83aae4e739870d7cdb38" name="Observer.php" /></dir></dir></dir></target></contents><dependencies><required><php><min>5.2.0</min><max>6.0.0</max></php></required></dependencies><authors><author><name>goivvy.com</name><user>ivvy_ru</user><email>go@ivvy.ru</email></author></authors><date>2013-07-22</date><compatibile /><channel>community</channel><description>calculate final price based on formula</description></package>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing should differ in a manual vs connect installation if you copied all the files correctly, you might have forgotten to add the formula to eval() in the admin panel in your first installation.

The extension should check first if the formula exists and that is not being made [here](http://www.goivvy.com/blog/apply-custom-formula-to-product-price).